# RedQuits (or alternative) on Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, window-manager, productivity

I have installed [RedQuits](http://www.carsten-mielke.com/redquits.html) on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).  Unfortunately, it is not working *at all*.

I have made sure that RedQuits has access to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, but it seems to not work.

Currently, the RedQuits website states it works with Mac OS X 10.6.

**Does anybody know how to get RedQuits working with Yosemite, or of any alternatives that will cause the close button to quit an application?**

Comment: For reference, RedQuits works on Mojave just fine. "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility"

Comment: Still works on Monterey

Answer (score 8):

I just had this same accessibility issue using RedQuits 2.0 and was able to get it working with Yosemite (10.10).  Just follow the steps below.

1. Download RedQuits v2.0 [RedQuits Download Link](http://redquits.s3.amazonaws.com/RedQuits_v2.pkg)
2. Double click the downloaded package. (You will most likely get a warning telling you the software was not downloaded from the mac store)
3. Click the apple icon in the top left of your screen and navigate to [System Preferences] [Security and Privacy] [Privacy]
4. Click Accessibility menu item on the left panel.
5. Click the lock in the bottom left corner to make changes, then click the ReQuits checkbox in the right pane.[image: Accessibility Panel]
6. Launch the RedQuits app again, and check all three checkboxes when prompted.
7. Launch the terminal app (You can find this by searching for 'terminal' with the spotlight search in the upper right of your screen.
8. Paste the following code into the terminal and hit [Enter]

   sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db 'delete from access where client like "%RedQuits%"'
9. Restart your computer.
10. Once again navigate to [System Preferences] [Security and Privacy] [Privacy]
11. Click Accessibility, click the lock to make changes, check RedQuits.
12. It should now be working.  If not try restarting your computer once more.

Comment: O MY GOOOOD!!!!! YOU ARE EPIC)!!! YOU SAVE MY NERVES

Comment: Work on Bigsur. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution for you, it's elegant and simple and free:

1. google and download:

[image: bettertouchtool]
go to global tab then..

[image: Imgur]

then to 'others' menu point

[image: Imgur]

then to

[image: Imgur]

then select as in picture

[image: Imgur]

as you can see I use the Command + Q, shortcut command, then...

[image: Imgur]

should look like this done
you close this app and u done.  now try it! by double-clicking any app title bar will quit that app.

her is the bonus:

[image: Imgur]

green button maximize window ,same as in windows.

[image: Imgur]

this is the final look.

enjoy!

peace

rg
:)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, this doesn't help me maintain my current workflow.

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely useful. In my case I wanted a certain application to minimize instead of Quit when the red button was clicked. Was able to do this with BTT.

Answer (score 1):

For newer version of macOS. [Swift Quit](https://swiftquit.com/) is great alternative.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's a new SIMBL/Macforge plugin called Goodbye has the same effect as RedQuits: https://github.com/MacEnhance/Goodbye Disclaimer: I had a small amount of involvement in this plugins development.

Compiled version here: https://github.com/Wowfunhappy/Goodbye/releases/tag/2020.04.15

Unlike RedQuits, Goodbye injects the code directly into the application. This is a somewhat harsher method, and it means SIP needs to be temporarily turned off while installing—but it also means there's no longer a weird delay between closing the window and the app actually quitting. Goodbye also lets you blacklist specific apps that you want to stay open via `defaults write [app.bundle.id] GoodbyeBlacklist -bool true`.

If you're on a modern version of macOS (10.13+), [Macforge](https://www.macenhance.com/macforge) is the best way to install SIMBL plugins. However, there are [other](https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL) [variations](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/simbl-on-the-last-version-of-mavericks.2231024/) [of](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL) SIMBL for older versions of OS X.